# Xpath - Find span, exclude child i attribute

Tags: xpath

Given the following object:

```
<span id="PartComment">
REMAN WATER PUMP
<i>w/2.05" DIAMETER THERMOSTAT OUTLET - SUPPLIED w/PULLEY
</i>
</span>
```

I'm trying to come up with an xpath that should locate me only the span by id and the text inside it (REMAN WATER PUMP). Unfortunately, the text inside the `i` is also caught up.

I was thinking of something like:

```
//span[@id='PartComment'][not(self::i)]
```

But it keeps selecting the `i` text too.

Thanks for stopping by!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
//span[@id='PartComment']/text()
```