# Selenium WebDriver - Xpath to select span and exclude a child node

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211861/xpath-find-span-exclude-child-i-attribute) question today, but mistakenly I did not specify the scope of it, which is for use in Selenium Webdriver.

So I have this td:

```
<td>
<span id="PartComment">
REMAN WATER PUMP
<i>w/2.05" DIAMETER THERMOSTAT OUTLET - SUPPLIED w/PULLEY
</i>
</span>
</td>
```

And I want an xpath to locate only the text REMAN WATER PUMP to later convert it to a string.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='lblPartComment']/text()"));
```

But the problem is that since I'm only locating the text, and not a DOM object, WebDriver won't be able to treat it as such:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //span[@id='lblPartComment']/text() is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression "//span[@id='lblPartComment']/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

Can you please provide an alternative to that xpath? One that locates the text I mentioned above, and excludes the text inside the `i`?

Also, [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651033/webdriver-cant-find-is-object-xraywrapper-object-text).

Thanks

Comment: I can offer you locator but can you tell me: is the text "REMAN WATER PUMP" changing? I mean, do you want to verify it for different test cases? Because there is an XPath syntax is for locating the span only by this partial text.

Comment: I want to locate the span and extract the text inside the span, and exclude any text in the i or any other child nodes that may come up. Yes the reman water pump text may change, but that's irrelevant because I'm locating the span. Additionally, reading around I found that //span[@id='PartComment']/[not(self::i)] could work, but this keeps adding the text in the other child nodes too, so it doesn't work for me.
So basically what I need is a way for me to use the not function in xpath to exclude the i node (at least for now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
var firstText = this.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='lblPartComment']")).Text;
var firstChildText = this.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='lblPartComment']/i")).Text;
firstText = firstText.Replace(firstChildText, string.Empty);
```

Locate both the parent and the child elements, get their text and replace the child's text with empty string. :)

Comment: this is C# but the code for Java should be identical, the idea matters. :)

Comment: I am not fluent yet in translating code, could you translate that to java please? @Anton Angelov

Comment: String firstText = this.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='lblPartComment']")).Text;
String firstChildText = this.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='lblPartComment']i")).Text;
firstText = firstText.replace(firstChildText, "");

Comment: I'm getting that //span[@id='lblPartComment']i is an invalid xpath...are we sure that the 'i' at the end is correct? @Anton Angelov

Comment: sorry it should be //span[@id='lblPartComment']/i

Comment: I don't actually use Java. Can you read the documentation for the replace method. The approach is correct you just need the proper syntax for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. referred from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325454/how-to-get-text-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-via-the-python-api-without)

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String text = (String) js.executeScript("var parent = arguments[0];"
            + "var child = parent.firstChild;"
            + "var ret = \"\";"
            + "while(child) {"
            + "    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)"
            + "        ret += child.textContent;"
            + "    child = child.nextSibling;"
            + "}"
            + "return ret;", driver.findElement(By.id("PartComment")));
```